# Biztalk WCF Service Publishing Wizard - empty request schema / without request message

Tags: biztalk

I Would like to create a WCF endpoint (Recieve location) with the wizard but do not want to specify a request schema.

I'm interested in creating a operation like:

> MyReturnType GetThings()

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Ehmm...that method has no arguments. Do you want that WCF sevice to accept requests of any schema? Can you tell me the purpose of this?

Comment: Hi @ArsenMagomedov , exactly, I dont want my operation to have any arguments, like: AirPortCollection GetAllAirportsInTheWorld()

Comment: You need some way of creating an instance of the biz app. an activating receive shape (ie some kind of message) is the only way I know how to do this. You could go outside of biz and publish your own WCF service that makes up a message and sends it to a Biz service that then does nothing with the message. But this is a rather awful solution if you ask me.

Comment: I guess you want that message for activating some kind of DB polling inside of orchestration using .NET helper. Is that so?)) You can't make a WCF receive location without receiving anything. You can create some simple schema  with one node and use it as activating argument of that service method, but as @Jeyenne said, thats a bad solution.